# Undefined mixin susy-grid-background in susy 2

Tags: sass, susy-compass, susy-sass

I'm trying to get Susy 2 to work on my computer. I have tried several ways of installing but none of them seem to completely work.

First attempt:
Installed compass, susy and sass manually through a gem install compass etc. I then created a project (compass create) and included the @import 'susy'. All seemed well but then the span mixin would not work.

Second attempt:
Uninstalled compass, sass and susy. Installed the gem compass-susy-plugin. Created a compass project with -r susy -u susy. This time span worked but the susy-grid-background mixin was undefined.

Third attempt:
Uninstalled compass susy plugin, compass and sass. Installed sass, susy and the gem compass --pre. Now the span mixin works but the susy-grid-background mixin is undefined. We are really not getting this. It is supposed to be really easy but something is going terribly wrong here.

I now have this Gem list:

Compass (1.0.0.alpha.19),
Sass (3.3.8, 3.2.19),
Susy (2.1.2)

I have tested this on two different computers (mac and windows). Same results.

My screen.scss has a include of base and in the base there is an include of susy. Config.rb has the require susy in it. There is no package.json file.

I hope someone has some pointers.

Comment: [This guy](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sass-lang/UKuxyt3iCeE/Sn1lmKe67l4J) seems to have the same problem? His prob seemed to be: Calling function before import and the generated files trying to import "susy/susy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just the grid that's the problem, I use:

```
@include container(show);
```

or

```
@include container(show overlay);
```

Have you looked up the documentation on http://susy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ ?

Comment: I think the problem was that we thought the susy-grid-background was supposed to work. But i can't find it anywhere in the docs, so probably it just does not exist... We indeed found another way to show the grid. 

Thanks for the reply!